Symfony 6.4 - Unable to declare an abstract form type as a service
In my Symfony 6.4 project, I'm trying to declare an abstract service in services.yaml by doing the following :
config/services.yaml
imports:
- { resource: services/ }
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
       autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
       autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

config/services/forms.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true

  # parent form
  App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract:
    arguments:
      $authorizationChecker: '@security.authorization_checker'
      $tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
      $phpHandlers: '%php_handlers%'
      $nodeJsHandlers: '%nodeJs_handlers%'
    abstract:  true

  # children forms
  App\Admin\Form\HostingFormCreate:
    parent: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract
    class: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormCreate
    calls:
      - [setGroupManager, ['@App\Services\Managers\GroupManager']]
    tags: [form.type]

  App\Admin\Form\HostingFormUpdate:
    parent: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract
    class: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormUpdate
    calls:
      - [setHostnameManager, ['@App\Services\Managers\HostnameManager']]
    tags: [form.type]
...

The HostingFormAbstract class is extending AbstractType from symfony/form package :
namespace App\Admin\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

abstract class HostingFormAbstract extends AbstractType
{
    
    private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage;
    private AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker;
    private array $phpHandlers;
    private array $nodeJsHandlers;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authorizationChecker, array $phpHandlers, array $nodeJsHandlers)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
        $this->phpHandlers = $phpHandlers;
        $this->nodeJsHandlers = $nodeJsHandlers;
    }
...

And with that, I get the following error while going on my symfony app :

The service "App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract" tagged "form.type" must not be abstract.


For more context, I'm rewriting a Symfony 3.4 app into a new Symfony 6.4 app.
It was working fine on 3.4, but now it seems that in services.yaml, you can't declare an abstract service/class extending the AbstractType class.
I tried to add a custom tag in the yaml for this service, but it didn't change anything.
I didn't find any workaround on Symfony documentation, and it seems odd to me that you can't do that. Maybe I missed something.
If anyone as an idea on how to do this...
Thanks !
Edit, working solution :
It seems that there is something wrong with my multiple .yaml files registering the services.
Here is what I had to do in order to have my service registered :

I moved all the services of config/services/forms.yaml in config/services.yaml
I added autoconfigure: false to my App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract service

config/services.yaml
imports:
- { resource: services/ }

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
 ...

App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract:
    class: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract
    autoconfigure: false
    arguments:
        $authorizationChecker: '@security.authorization_checker'
        $tokenStorage: '@security.token_storage'
        $phpHandlers: '%php_handlers%'
        $nodeJsHandlers: '%nodeJs_handlers%'
    abstract: true

App\Admin\Form\HostingFormCreate:
    parent: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract
    class: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormCreate
    calls:
        - [ setGroupManager, [ '@App\Services\Managers\GroupManager' ] ]
    tags: [ form.type ]

App\Admin\Form\HostingFormUpdate:
    parent: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract
    class: App\Admin\Form\HostingFormUpdate
    calls:
        - [ setHostnameManager, [ '@App\Services\Managers\HostnameManager' ] ]
    tags: [ form.type ]


Are you trying to inject the HostingFormAbstract directly some place? Normally you would have some additional form classes extending HostingFormAbstract which have the parent service container attribute. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html

Yes I do inject the HostingFormAbstract in some children services. I have updated the services.yaml block code in my post to show you how I do.  @Cerad

It looks like it should work. Maybe autowire is picking up the class without your service definition file? Do you only have one services.yaml file?

I have multiple yaml files where I set services. There is the main services.yaml file and I have created some others .yaml files where I fill some services corresponding to a category (forms.yaml, admins.yaml, commands.yaml, etc...). Those files are in a subfolder called "services", and I import them via the main services.yaml file via the "imports" key. I have updated my post in order to be more clear.

I could be on completely the wrong track here but autowire could be picking up your abstract class twice because of multiple services.yaml files. In particular if your master config/service.yaml file has the usual      App\:         resource: '../src/' lines then it will pick everything up and basically try to create the same service twice.

I also thought it could be a problem related to my differents .yaml files, but I haven't had a problem with other services as persistent as this one on any of the others .yaml files... If I register the HostingFormAbstract service in the main services.yaml I have the same issue unfortunately :/

In fact you were quite right @Cerad, it was a part of the problem, thanks ! The other part was in the yceruto answer

It's the default behavior of autoconfigure option, setting the form.type tag to all FormTypeInterface classes under the service scope.
However, you can exclude any service from been auto-tagged by setting autoconfigure: false like this:
App\Admin\Form\HostingFormAbstract:
    autoconfigure: false
    // ...

and then the error should disappear.

You're right it's working with autoconfigure set to false !
But it's not the only thing that I had to do, I also moved my HostingFormAbstract service and all the children services in the my main services.yaml file instead of forms.yaml in order to make the registration work. So @Cerad was also right, there is something wrong with my multiple services files.
Thanks to the both of you for your help !
